# jCarousel on Drupal

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-6, jcarousel

I have the jCarousel module on my Drupal-6 website. On my page I have the following code:

```
<?php
$items = array (
  0 => '<img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&amp;text=Bio" />',
  1 => '<img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&amp;text=Bio" />',
      ....
);
$options = array (
  'wrap' => 'circular',
  'auto' => '5',
);
print theme('jcarousel', $items, $options);
?>
```

The problem is the when the page originally loads, It loads the images in a list and then puts them into a carousel. How can I make it so that the images load directly into a carousel instead of displaying as a list first?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the actual full code, I'm guessing a simple 'overflow:hidden' could solve the problem.
As far as I know the carousel items always need to be in a list, you just don't want them to display outside of the container while loading?

Comment: All the carousels kind of do this. But I guess because my images are larger the lag time is longer. When the images are loading the are displayed as a list but after it is loaded it is contained in a carousel.